# Call web api c# by passing oauth token along with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-routing

I'm using custom oauth in web API for authentication. Now i want to call web api method from MVC controller. 
Web API method:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UserById")]
    public IEnumerable GetUserById(string idValue)
    {
        long ID = idValue != "" ? Convert.ToInt64(idValue) : -1;
        using (var db = new DataModelContext())
        {
            IEnumerable query = (from b in db.User.Include(u => u.EmailAddresses).ToList() 
               where b.Id == ID
               select new { b.Id, UserName = b.UserName, b.EmailAddresses }).ToList();

            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

MVC controller:

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetUserById(long id)
    {
        string baseUrl = Common.GetAPIUrl();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Common.GetoAuth().access_token);

        var values = new JObject();
        values.Add("idValue",id.ToString());

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(values.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/api/User/UserById", content).Result;

        string resultJSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return View("UserDetail",resultJson);
    }
}
```

Some how its not working, i'm not able to rectify issue why its not working. When i'm calling API direct URL from postman its working fine. like http://localhost:55362/api/UserById/2 or  http://localhost:55362/api/UserById?idvalue=2. its not working for only httpclient call.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". What is happening? Is it throwing an exception? If so please provide the details,

Comment: NO its not throwing exception. Its returning this message:
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49963/api/User/UserById
No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the name 'UserById'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase if you still stuck up with this issue. Please do the following to make it work.

WebApiConfig: Action Api should come above the controller Route

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ActionApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

On the Api Method: Add the "FromBody" attribute to the parameter.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UserById")]
public IEnumerable GetUserById([FromBody]string idValue)
{
    long ID = idValue != "" ? Convert.ToInt64(idValue) : -1;
    using (var db = new DataModelContext())
    {
        IEnumerable query = (from b in db.User.Include(u => u.EmailAddresses).ToList() 
           where b.Id == ID
           select new { b.Id, UserName = b.UserName, b.EmailAddresses }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have enabled CORS in your webapiconfig.cs file.

Also, verify your route mapping

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
            var mvcSiteURL = "Define your MVC site URL here"; //Example: http://localhost:5906

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(mvcSiteURL, "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                              name: "ActionApi",
                             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional} );
```

Comment: That's not the case, already CORS is enabled. Also without parameter simple action call is working. Only issue came for parameter action.

Comment: There is a difference in the uri you have tried in Postman and HttpClient. http client uses /api/User/UserById", whereas postman url doesn't uses UserById

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check whether you have the route mapping as per my answer and the order the of the route mapping, if you have more than one.

Comment: yes routing is also same there. and i updated my postman url in question. it was /api/UserById not /api/user

Comment: Can you post the fiddler trace for request and response details

Comment: Also try this as well.  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

Comment: i tried fiddler but unable to understand how to get it trace. let me try defaultrequestheader

Comment: its still same after using client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);